# Is there a way to set default plot styles?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The lines in the default plot style is too thin. I could change the line width by

```
ax=plt.gca()
ax.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(2)
```

But then I also need to change the tick width and text style to make them look similar. Also, I want the tick inside the graph. I want to plot a lot of plots in the same style. Is there anyway that I can define the plotting style at the beginning, then each time I use plt, they use the same plotting styles?

```
#To change the style
plt.style.use('classic')#But I couldn't find the styles that I like
#To change tick direction and width
plt.tick_params(direction='in',width=2)
#To change axis lines width
ax=plt.gca()
ax.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(2)
#To change x lable
plt.xlabel('xlabel',fontsize=16)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define a custom plotting style in Matplotlib and apply it consistently to all your plots. This allows you to set various properties, including line width, tick parameters, text style, and more, in one place.

make a file called "mystyle.mplstyle"

```
  axes.linewidth: 2
  xtick.direction: in
  ytick.direction: in
  xtick.major.width: 2
  ytick.major.width: 2
  font.size: 16
```

Then when you would like to use it in code you just load this parms through

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('path/to/mystyle.mplstyle')
```